# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' and warning

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to make a simple program to extract words from paragraphs in a web page.
my code looks like this -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator

def start(url):
    word_list = []
    source_code = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
    for post_text in soup.find_all('p'):
        cont = post_text.string
        words = cont.lower().split()
        for each_word in words:
            print(each_word)
            word_list.append(each_word)


start('https://lifehacker.com/why-finding-your-passion-isnt-enough-1826996673')
```

First I am getting this warning -
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 17 of the file D:/Projects/Crawler/Main.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

```
BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})
```

to this:

```
 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "html.parser")

  markup_type=markup_type))
```

and then there is this error in the end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/Crawler/Main.py", line 17, in <module>
    start('https://lifehacker.com/why-finding-your-passion-isnt-enough-1826996673')
  File "D:/Projects/Crawler/Main.py", line 11, in start

    words = cont.lower().split()
```

> AttributeError: `'NoneType'` object has no attribute `'lower'`

I have tried searching, but not able to resolve or understand the problem.

Comment: `for post_text in soup.find_all('p'): print(post_text)` what do you see? I suspect you got no matches and it returns `None`

Comment: You're asking two separate questions, which will have two separate answers, which doesn't fit the Q&A format of Stack Overflow. Especially since they're both most likely duplicates of existing questions with good answers, but there's no duplicate question that answers both.

Comment: Anyway, for the warning, [read the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). For the error, if a function or attribute reference returns `None`, you obviously can't call `lower()` on that—and, as the docs explain, if you try to search for or navigate to something that doesn't exist, `None` is what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing that page using the paragraph tag `<p>`, but that tag does not always have textual content associated to it. For instance, if you were to instead run:

```
def start(url):
    word_list = []
    source_code = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
    for post_text in soup.find_all('p'):
        print(post_text)
```

You would see that you're getting hits off of things like advertisements: `<p class="ad-label=bottom"></p>`.  As others have stated in the comment, `None` type does not have string methods, which is literally what your error is referring to.

A simple way to guard against this would be to wrap a section of your function in a [try/except block](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

```
for post_text in soup.find_all('p'):
    try:
        cont = post_text.string
        words = cont.lower().split()
        for each_word in words:
            print(each_word)
            word_list.append(each_word)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```